# Space delimited with 'ssconvert'

Tags: import-from-excel, gnumeric, ssconvert

I want to use `ssconvert` from Gnumeric to convert an Excel file to .txt file. The command should be:

```
ssconvert -O 'separator= ' excel.xlsx result.txt
```

However, it doesn't insert `' '`  between cells. For example `A B` is written as `AB`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

ssconvert -O "separator=' '"  excel.xlsx result.txt